# Cannot be executed by DataflowRunner

Tags: go, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

"Dataflow" and "DataflowRunner" do not work with the "--runner" option set when executing processing with Apache Beam Go SDK.

I checked the official Apache Beam reference and Go manual, but I don't understand the cause.
Could you please tell me a concrete solution?

###### Commands executed on the command line

```
go run test.go --runner=DataflowRunner \
          --project=[my-project] \
          --region=[my-region] \
          --temp_location=gs://[my-gs-bucket] \
          --staging_location=gs://[my-gs-bucket] \
          --worker_harness_container_image=apache/beam_go_sdk:lates
```

###### Actual code

```
    package main

    import (
        "context"
        "flag"
        "reflect"

        "github.com/bramp/morebeam/csvio"
        "github.com/apache/beam/sdks/go/pkg/beam"
        "github.com/apache/beam/sdks/go/pkg/beam/log"
        "github.com/apache/beam/sdks/go/pkg/beam/x/beamx"
        "github.com/apache/beam/sdks/go/pkg/beam/io/bigqueryio"
        "github.com/apache/beam/sdks/go/pkg/beam/options/gcpopts"
    )

    type Csvdata struct {
        id   string
        name string
        age  string
    }

    var (
        BQ = "[my-project]:[my-data-set].[my-file]"
    )

    func main() {

        flag.Parse()

        beam.Init()

        ctx := context.Background()
            
        p := beam.NewPipeline()
        s := p.Root()
        
     log.Infof(ctx, "Started pipeline on scope: %s", s)
        
     parse := csvio.Read(s, "gs://[my-gcs-bucket]", reflect.TypeOf(Csvdata{}))

        if BQ != "" {
            project := gcpopts.GetProject(ctx)
            bigqueryio.Write(s, project, BQ, parse)
        }
        
        beamx.Run(ctx, p)
    }
```

###### Execution result

```
2021/06/17 01:29:15 Started pipeline on scope: root
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it should be --runner=dataflow .. lowercase

Comment: Correct.

At some point "DataflowRunner" was also registered to match the other SDKs.
https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/go/pkg/beam/runners/dataflow/dataflow.go#L146

Though it's a separate issue that it doesn't simply fail when the lookup fails. Very weird.

Comment: Also,  Go can't serialize data automatically if the fields are unexported. Export the fields in Csvdata, and data won't get lost when serialized. Most of the same limitations as the encoding/json package, for the same reasons. https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#Marshal